# Displaying array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, components

I have this array that is suppose to display a random poem on the screen each time it is loaded. I have the array made but for some reason it does not display on my screen.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<dom-module id="poem-element">
  <template>
    <div></div>
    <div id="poems"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "poem-element",
      ready: function() {
        var newArray = ["poem1", "poem2", "poem3"];
        var random = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) - 1);
        this.querySelector("#poems").innerHTML= poems[randomPoem];
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: thank you, yea I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Your random number has an inclusive range of `-1` through `3`. It should be `0` through `2`. Change it to this: `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * newArray.length)`

Comment: ...and always consult your developer console first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is called `newArray`, not `poems`, and your random is called `random`, not `randomPoem`. Try this instead:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

<dom-module id="poem-element">

  <template>

        <div>
    </div>

        <div  id="poems"> </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "poem-element",
            ready: function () {

   var poems =["poem1", "poem2", "poem3"];
                var randomPoem = Math.floor(Math.random() * newArray.length);
                this.querySelector("#poems").innerHTML= poems[randomPoem];
      }

        })


    </script>

</dom-module>
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the `random` number to be between 0 and 2, as per Squint's suggestion in the comments above.